# get cc_type value in magento

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway

How could I get the value (text, not the code) of `cc_type` in my payment gateway model?

In payment gateway model for `authorize()` and `capture()` I do get `$payment` object from which I do get `cc_type` as `$payment->getCcType()` but it returns the code for the `cc_type` how could I get the value of the code. e.g., it return **VI** for the **VISA**. So, how could I get **VISA** from the `$payment` or `$payment->getCcType()`?

Comment: Can you try with `$payment->getCcTypeName();` ?

Comment: @Rikesh: it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have the cc code (`'VI'`, `'MA'`, etc.) at that point you could use:

```
// $sType = 'VI';
$sType = $payment->getCcType();
$aType = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getCcTypes();
if (isset($aType[$sType])) {
    $sName = $aType[$sType];
}
else {
    $sName = Mage::helper('payment')->__('N/A');
}
```

If you already have the `Mage_Payment_Model_Info` block at that point you could use:

```
$sName = $payment->getMethod()->getInfoInstance()->getCcTypeName();
```

Comment: your code `$payment->getMethod()->getInfoInstance()->getCcTypeName();` is not returning the `cc_type_name`. but your above solution is right. I'd done that meanwhile. if you would update your answer to make it work for all types(not only for VI) then I'll accept it